# How can I migrate the data from the iCloud store file to a new store file in local storage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, persistence, icloud

I have `iCloud` in my app. I've removed `iCloud` from my app, but on ios 6 app crashes and I get this message:

```
  -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:](1055):
```

`CoreData: Ubiquity: Error:` A persistent store which has been previously added to a coordinator using the iCloud integration options must always be added to the coordinator with the options present in the options dictionary. If you wish to use the store without `iCloud`, migrate the data from the `iCloud` store file to a new store file in local storage.

How can I solve this error? How can I migrate the data from the `iCloud` store file to a new store file in local storage?

Comment: I have an identical post to yours. You were first, so I apologize. Have you figured a workaround/solution? I have simply removed the localstore for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES, I have this question too.
I want to turn a iCloud store to a local store

---

### Solution 1 :Moving managedObjects one-by-one to the localStore.

But if you have a large database, it will be so slow.

So I found a second solution yesterday.

---

### Solution 2: Editing the metadata of the iCloud store,

### and saving it to the new location.

After you remove "com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.*" keys in metadata, 
you'll get a fully local store.

---

Here is my code for solution 2:

There are some properties already set:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPersistentStore *iCloudStore;
//represent the iCloud store already using 
//(after [coordinator addPersistentStore] you get this NSPersistentStore)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *iCloudStoreURL;
//represent the iCloud store real location
//(it is the URL you send to the [coordinator addPersistentStore])

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *iCloudStoreLocalVersionURL;
//represent the location of local version store you want to save
```

And the migrate method:

```
-(void)migrateCloudStoreToLocalVersion
{
    if(!self.iCloudStore)
        return;

    // remove previous local version
    [FILE_MANAGER removeItemAtURL:self.iCloudStoreLocalVersionURL
                            error:nil];

    // made a copy from original location to the new location
    [FILE_MANAGER copyItemAtURL:self.iCloudStoreURL
                          toURL:self.iCloudStoreLocalVersionURL
                          error:nil];

    //prepare meta data
    NSDictionary *iCloudMetadata = [self.coordinator metadataForPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore].copy;

    NSMutableDictionary *localVersionMetadata = iCloudMetadata.mutableCopy;
    for(NSString * key in iCloudMetadata){
        if([key hasPrefix:@"com.apple.coredata.ubiquity"]){
            [localVersionMetadata removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
    }

    //modify iCloud store
    [self.coordinator setMetadata:localVersionMetadata forPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore];
    [self.coordinator setURL:self.iCloudStoreLocalVersionURL forPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore];

    //save to the localVersion location
    [self.context save:nil];

    //restore iCloud store
    [self.coordinator setMetadata:iCloudMetadata forPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore];
    [self.coordinator setURL:self.iCloudStoreURL forPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore];
}
```

Then you can use the `iCloudStoreLocalVersionURL` to using the local version store.

You can use this local version store as local store, without any error.

**Note:**

Notice the `NSStoreUUIDKey` in the metadata,

you can optional replace it for the new store.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped a lot.  I use a slightly modified version of this where I access the iCloud store, create a dictionary that excludes the ubiquity values, and then call migratePersistentStore to move it locally and it is working.

Comment: This may need an update for iOS 7/8. I was trying to do this and got a write error. I followed  the code laid out here to update meta data before loading my store. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingPersistentStores.html

I then loaded my store and updated it's url with the code above. Worked for me.

Comment: @gabe.roze iOS 7/8 use a totally new iCloud CoreData  system. So this answer is not fit for iOS 7/8.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to change out the UUID number too,   I would get errors on the next run of the app that it was loading the same store twice.  so i made this modification

```
    if (!self.iCloudStore) return;
NSError *error = nil;

NSURL* localStoreURL = [self fallbackStoreURL];

 NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

 if (!self.fallbackStore) [self loadFallbackStore:&error];

NSString* fallBackUUID;

//find UUID of original to put back in later
NSDictionary *fallBackMetadata = [_psc metadataForPersistentStore:self.fallbackStore].copy;
for(NSString* key in fallBackMetadata)
{
    if([key hasPrefix:@"NSStoreUUID"])
    {
        fallBackUUID = [fallBackMetadata objectForKey:key];
        break;
    }
}

[fm removeItemAtURL:localStoreURL error:nil];


//prepare meta data
NSDictionary *iCloudMetadata = [_psc metadataForPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore].copy;
NSMutableDictionary *localVersionMetadata = iCloudMetadata.mutableCopy;
for(NSString* key in iCloudMetadata)
{
    if([key hasPrefix:@"com.apple.coredata.ubiquity"])
    {
        [localVersionMetadata removeObjectForKey:key];
    }

    if([key hasPrefix:@"NSStoreUUID"])
    {
         if (fallBackUUID) [localVersionMetadata setObject:fallBackUUID forKey:key];
    }
}


//modify iCloud store
[_psc setMetadata:localVersionMetadata forPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore];
[_psc setURL:localStoreURL forPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore];

// make a copy from original location to the new location
[fm copyItemAtURL:[self iCloudStoreURL]
                      toURL:localStoreURL
                      error:nil];

 [_fallbackContext save:nil];


[_psc setMetadata:iCloudMetadata forPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore];
[_psc setURL:[self iCloudStoreURL] forPersistentStore:self.iCloudStore];
```